# How to make classification with deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, weka

I have ARFF(Attribute-Relation File Format)that use in [weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) this file contain binary features (0,1) and the class label also binary (0,1) .
I want to make classification for this file with [Convolutional neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network)
.
How can I write code for my model , all tutorialwrite about classification for image .
Can you help me

Comment: Sorry to say that, but you cannot run CNNs with Weka.

Comment: I know that but I have ARFF file I can change it to excel sheet want to run CNN on it , how can I do that ?all material write about image I want material on CNN on excel file or ARFF

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I knew that CNN used for 3D like images so I can't use it on my file another algorithm from deep learning like Deep Belief network can use